# Any better way to pause operation and wait for event other than Thread.sleep in a Quartz Job?

Tags: java, wait, scheduler, sleep, executorservice

I have a web app which has a class ClassA which implements quartz job. Scheduling of this class is done via quartz xml scheduler at a specific time lets say 6 am;
the aim is to check for files, and if present process them. If they are not keep checking them at regular intervals (i.e. 15 mins) till 8 am; At 8 am if they are still not there, just error out;

Is there any other way than Sleep? I tried implementing with Callable, Runnable, Future - but I think the main ClassA will still have to wait eitherways. So is Thread.Sleep the only possibility?

```
public class ClassA implements Job {

    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext _jobExecutionContext) throws JobExecutionException {

        boolean bfilesnotfound = functionAllFilesPresent();

        if (bfilesnotfound) {
            do {
                Thread.sleep(15mins);
                //check if files are there; if they are present exit this while loop and process
                //or check if it is 8 am; if it is already 8 am terminate and send error notification.          
            }
        }


        private boolean functionAllFilesPresent () {
            //check and return all files;
            //I can ofcourse implement File Listener; but that is not the scope of the current question
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Schedule another job for 6:15, then another at 6:30, etc. I.e., let Quartz do its job.

Comment: If, the 6:00 job is successful then the rest of jobs would be redundant. Also the timeout at 8 am is data driven e.g. at run time the value can be changed to 9 am and the source would run till that time. If I really want to run the same job multiple times, I can just change the Quartz xml file via code to set a new time for ClassA, and Quartz would automatically take care of restarting the same job via execute of ClassA- My question is can it be done with simple ExecutorService or some combination of Future and Runnable/Callable?

Comment: Right. So if the 6:00 job succeeds, don’t schedule another. Jobs can schedule other jobs, and they can signal success or failure to Quartz to let it manage retries.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Can this be done with ExecutorService or some combination of Future and runnable/callable?

Comment: You asked for a better way than sleeping. Using the features of Quart to ensure reliability is better than mixing scheduling mechanisms that don’t coordinate with each other. If that is not what you want to know, please amend your question to clarify. For example, perhaps you just want `execute()` to return without blocking, even if some later action is “scheduled.”

Comment: So taking your suggestion - i would somehow need to inject a scheduler instance in ClassA? Is that what you are suggesting? Do you have a concrete example of how a Scheduler instance can be injected in a Quartz XML driven configuration with GuiceJobFactory? Otherwise if I am supposed to create a local scheduler in ClassA - where should i call its shutdown?